# Replace domain in url without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

In Javascript or jQuery, I need to be able to replace the domain section of the url only without the page reloading. The domain can vary so I can't hard code something in.

For example, I need to change these;

```
https://domainone.co.uk/page/id/extra-info
https://domaintwo.co.uk/page/id/extra-info
```

To

```
https://mynewdomain.co.uk/page/id/extra-info
```

Comment: This isn't possible. Imagine the security implications if it was. I could make 'mysite.com' look like Gmail and then phish your login details.

Comment: Not only is it not possible, its also fairly malicious.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki note that dupe is regarding changing the URL path/querystring/fragment, not the domain.